# Does Gdiplus::Font::Clone() duplicate the underlying TTF data?

Tags: fonts, gdi+

This is in the context of a C++ MFC application in Visual Studio. Some windows use Gdiplus.

Does the call `Gdiplus::Font::Clone()` duplicate the actual TTF font data, or just a small class that manages it?

I'm worried because when I create many child windows (buttons, labels, etc), I pass a pointer to the parent's `Gdiplus::Font` to the child and the child clones it. I would HOPE the underlying font data is just in a single location and some sort of reference counting occurs under the hood, instead of having dozens of copies of that stuff all over the place.

So I tried both methods and didn't see a real difference in memory usage, which surprised me. That seems like strong evidence that the TTF font isn't really being "cloned", but instead some small data classes to manage it are being cloned. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gdiplus::Font::Clone()` creates a copy of the Font object (i.e., the small class), not the TTF font data.